# I am building a compound interest calculator but I am not getting desired output for the below code

Tags: angular, typescript

Trying to call the function `compoundInterest()` on click of the button but the `for loop` is where I am having doubt, even after tracing the code I am not getting why the result is different?

```
investmentPerMonth = 10000;
numberOfYears:number = 3;
resultant = 0;
result:string = '';
investedPerYear = this.investmentPerMonth * 12;
    
investmentPerYear(): void {
    this.investedPerYear = this.investmentPerMonth*12;
}

compoundInterest(){
    if (this.numberOfYears > 0) {
        for (let i = this.numberOfYears; i >= 0; i--) {
            this.resultant =  this.resultant + ((this.investedPerYear + this.resultant) * 0.12) + this.investedPerYear;
        }
        this.result = this.resultant+'';
    }
    else {
        this.result = 'Number of Years cannot be less than 1';
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Hi Rohith, could you elaborate your question? Could you explain what exact result is expected and what is actual? If you mean that you expect to see the same result on every click, look at my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Do you expect to see the same result on every click? Then you need to reset the value of the resultant variable. When you click the button the first time, it uses the value that was set on initializing the component, which is 0. But the component is not reinitialized until you refresh the page or do it manually somehow else. It means you still have the same instance of the class with the same variable in its context. It keeps changes. So, the component uses the value of the resultant variable from the previous call on every next click.

Your compoundInterest function will return the same value if you reset the resultant inside of it:

```
 compoundInterest(){

    this.resultant = 0; // reset the value on every click

    if (this.numberOfYears > 0) {
      for (let i = this.numberOfYears; i >=0 ; i--) {
        this.resultant = 
          this.resultant +((this.investedPerYear + this.resultant)*0.12)+this.investedPerYear;
      }
    
      this.result = this.resultant+'';
    }
    else {
      this.result = 'Number of Years cannot be less than 1';
    }
  }
```

Does it answer your question?